# Ways of seeing relationships among views of a database?

Tags: sql, database, view

I need to extract data from views in a database in Microsoft SQLServer Management Studio. There are about 100 views in the database and I'm not familiar with most of the views. Is there any easier way to check the relationship among the views instead of click into each view and guessing their relationships?

I can only find the solution of seeing relationship of table but no views through Google search.

Answer (score 0):

For MS SQL try:

select 'insert into ViewDepend exec sp_depends ''' + name + '''' from sys.views

You'll need to define an appropriate table for ViewDepend.  It will have the same columns that sp_depends generates.